# How Custom Cell arr data share UIActivityViewController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

custom cell data click to share button. all data share using `UIActivityViewController`.
This code using array all data share. but i want only custom cell select data.

```
-(IBAction)btnshare:(id)sender{
  NSString *Number  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number%@", [arr valueForKey:@"number"]];
  NSString *Name  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name%@", [arr valueForKey:@"name"]];
  NSString *Address  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Address%@", [arr valueForKey:@"address"]];
  NSArray *objectsToShare = @[Number,Name,Address]; 
  UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
  NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                                   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                                   UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                                   UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                                   UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];
  activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;
  [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil]
}
```

this code using data share this formate.
      number(
        1234555565
        1223334444
      )
      name(
        hello
        faruk
      )
      address(
        avinash
        viabbaa
      )

BUT I want share this formate data
      number = 123265855
      name = hello
      address =avinash

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy! Combine them to a single string the way you want and then share.

```
NSString *combinedSharing = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number = %@ Name = %@ Address = %@", Number, Name, Address];
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[combinedSharing];
```

Btw, I recommend using proper naming convention for the variables.

For e.g. Use `strNumber` instead of `Number`. By adding, `str` will be more readable and in let other developer can know that, this variable is of string type.

Comment: but api data in array ..array data share..your formate is write bus..how to share array data.

Comment: I'm not getting you. Please elaborate more on your question.